# Compute norm between two integers interpreted as 4 bytes

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation, sse

I would like to write a function `norm2` which computes

```
uint32_t norm2(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) {
  return sqd( a & 0x000000FF     ,  b & 0x000000FF      )
       + sqd((a & 0x0000FF00)>> 8, (b & 0x0000FF00)>>  8)
       + sqd((a & 0x00FF0000)>>16, (b & 0x00FF0000)>> 16)
       + sqd((a & 0xFF000000)>>24, (b & 0xFF000000)>> 24);
}
uint32_t sqd(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) {
  uint32_t x = (a > b) ? a - b : b - a;
  return x*x;
}
```

What is the fastest way to do so under GCC? For example using assembler, SSE or similar.

Comment: Well to start with, you could mark the functions `inline` to allow the compiler to inline them. Other than that you may want to check the generated code with different optimization levels. It might be that GCC already can optimize it pretty well.

Comment: XMM registers in your case

Comment: While I don't know what *norm* means here, are you sure that you want to `shift` 0x0000FF00 by 8 bits first and then `bit-wise and` it with `b`, unlike what you do with the `a`?

Comment: I mean, in that case you could very well just replace all those next to `b &`s with `0x000000FF`s for an optimization...

Comment: @ThoAppelsin: I think it is just a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can read in sets of 4 for a and b, this can be done most cleanly/elegantly/efficiently by operating on 4-tuples because it will more fully saturate some of the instructions, so that all parts of the computation are part of the solution. The below solution uses up to SSSE3. Of course you will be better off to pull this out of the function, initialize constants up front, and find the most efficient way to put the values into the `__m128i` values depending on how the surrounding code is structured.

```
// a, b, and out, must all point to 4 integers
void norm2x4(const unsigned *a, const unsigned *b, unsigned *out) {
  // load up registers a and b, in practice this should probably not be in a function,
  // initialization of zero can happen outside of a loop,
  // and a and b can be loaded directly from memory into __m128i registers
  __m128i const zero = _mm_setzero_si128();
  __m128i       alo  = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)a); // this can also be adapted to aligned read instructions if you ensure an aligned buffer
  __m128i       blo  = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)b);

  // everything is already in the register where we need it except it
  // needs to be expanded to 2-byte ints for computations to work correctly
  __m128i       ahi = _mm_unpackhi_epi8(alo, zero);
  __m128i       bhi = _mm_unpackhi_epi8(blo, zero);
  alo               = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(alo, zero);
  blo               = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(blo, zero);
  alo               = _mm_sub_epi16(alo, blo);  // don't care if a - b, or b - a, the "wrong" one will result in a
  ahi               = _mm_sub_epi16(ahi, bhi);  // negation the square will later correct
  alo               = _mm_madd_epi16(alo, alo); // perform the square, and add every two adjacent
  ahi               = _mm_madd_epi16(ahi, ahi);
  alo               = _mm_hadd_epi32(alo, ahi); // add horizontal elements; ahi now contains 4 ints which are your results

  // store the result to output; this can be adapted to an aligned store if you ensure an aligned buffer
  // or the individual values can be extracted directly to 32-bit registers using _mm_extract_epi32
  _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)out, alo);
}
```

Comment: So this assumes, that `a[0]` to `a[3]` are valid, meaning that in the outer loop I have to increment using `a+=4`? (and the same for `b` and `out`)

Comment: @Danvil, Yes that is correct. You'd probably want a big buffer of all your "a" values, a separate big buffer of all your "b" values, and a third separate buffer for your output. If you 16-byte align these buffers you can also use _mm_load_si128 and _mm_store_si128 instead of  _mm_loadu_si128 and _mm_storeu_si128 respectively.

Answer (score 4):

Very simple to do the whole thing in a few instructions using SSE:

```
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t norm2(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) {
    const __m128i vec_zero = _mm_setzero_si128();
    __m128i vec_a = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(_mm_cvtsi32_si128(a), vec_zero);
    __m128i vec_b = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(_mm_cvtsi32_si128(b), vec_zero);
    __m128i vec_diff = _mm_sub_epi16(vec_a, vec_b);
    __m128i vec_dsq = _mm_madd_epi16(vec_diff, vec_diff);
    return _mm_cvtsi128_si32(_mm_hadd_epi32(vec_dsq, vec_dsq));
}
```

What we’re doing here is “unpacking” both a and b with a zero vector to expand the individual bytes into vectors of 16-bit integers.  We then subtract them (as 16-bit integers, avoiding risk of overflow), and multiply and accumulate them (as 32-bit integers, again avoiding risk of overflow).

I don’t have GCC installed to test with, but the above generates near-optimal assembly with clang; it shouldn’t be necessary to drop into assembly for such a simple task.

Comment: (I used `phaddd` for simplicity; one may reasonably prefer to use a shift or shuffle and `paddd` instead for performance on some architectures, or to avoid depending on SSSE3).

Comment: I was about to post something very similar but got pulled away from the computer for a bit. I'm not sure if it's worth posing near-duplicate code. But I wanted to mention you can very easily nearly quadruple your throughput. All you have to do is load a and b up with 4 values instead of 1. You then unpackhi on a and b as well as the the unpacklo you have in place. Then all the subtractions, mul+adds, horizontal adds, work on 4 values. At the end you can get your results out via 32-bit extract operations. If anyone desires more clarity on this I am happy to post it as an additional solution.

Comment: @Apriori: Yup, if the questioner has multiple `a`, `b` pairs sitting around, that’s absolutely the right thing to do.  (Of course, in the question as asked, that’s not an option).  Also, you’ll only quadruple your throughput on AVX2 machines; on SSE you’ll double it (it already uses half of an XMM reg for most of the operations).

Comment: I had a hunch you were wise to this =p But I do like to call it out for people who may be a bit new to SSE. Since the reason you use SSE in the first place is perf, often one must think of the problem on a little higher level (to saturate your registers, get values in the registers in the most efficient manner) in order to get the best perf as that was the point all along.

Comment: Agreed.  I would certainly up vote an answer showing how to implement, say, `void norm2(uint32_t * restrict results, const uint32_t *a, const uint32_t *b, size_t n)`.

Comment: actually with SSE about half your operations can happen on 4 values at a time. You have an extra unpack (and a move), its then true that the subtraction has to happen twice now, as well as the mul+add. But then the final horizontal add can operate on all 4 values at once, once again, that is there is still only one of these instructions. In addition this is also more optimal because on the superscalar architecture we are running on, more of these instructions will be executed in parallel. Indeed this operation fits very elegantly into sets of 4.

Comment: I posted a supplementary 4-tuple solution.

Answer (score 1):

a branchless version (as `square(-x) == square(x)`):

```
uint32_t sqd(int32_t a, int32_t b) {
  int32_t x = a - b;
  return x * x;
}

uint32_t norm2(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) {
  return sqd( a & 0x000000FF     , b &  0x000000FF      )
       + sqd((a & 0x0000FF00) >>  8, (b & 0x0000FF00) >>  8)
       + sqd((a & 0x00FF0000) >> 16, (b & 0x00FF0000) >> 16)
       + sqd((a & 0xFF000000) >> 24, (b & 0xFF000000) >> 24);
}
```

Comment: This is susceptible to underflow, whereas the previous version wasn't.

Comment: @AdamWright Underflow with integers, how can that happen?

Comment: @AdamWright: `a` and `b` are in `[0; 255]` (returned value will be in `[0; 65025]`). So I don't see any problem.

Comment: Okay, as far as I can understand, the concern was rather about *"overflow"* instead of *"underflow"*, but in any case, I cannot see how this version can be any more vulnerable to both over- or underflow more than the original version...